# A movie with a spacechip whose crew contained robots disguised as humans

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

This is about a movie I haven't seen myself, but which I only got told about. Moreover, the person who told me about it is no longer alive, so I cannot ask for more details. I remembered what I got told about it back than, and as it sounds like a movie I might enjoy, I'd like to know the title of it.

If I remember correctly, it was around the middle of the 2000s when that person saw it and then told me about it. It was on German TV, so it was probably not a very new movie back then.

Since the following is what I remember from a second-hand description of the movie, I cannot say for sure that everything is correct.

The story of the movie is about a test flight with a space ship where it shall be found out whether robots can replace humans in space flight. For this reason, the robots are disguised as humans, so that you cannot easily distinguish them from humans.

During the flight there are several incidents. One of them is that one of the robots sets an acceleration which is too high for humans. As result of that there's a period of silence on recordings made during the flight, which are later interpreted as failure of the captain.

At the end, the captain speaks with a man who from his behaviour seems very human. He talks about his life with his family somewhere in the US. But then, at the very end, he notices an injury of the skin of that man which doesn't look like an injury would look like for a human.

Does anyone have an idea what movie this might have been?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

quick google for

```
film android testflug beschleunigung
```

led to this:

http://sciencefictionlexikon.de/testflug-zum-saturn-test-pilota-pirxa-1978/

The movie "Test pilota Pirxa" is shown here:

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080010/

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like it is the right movie (and it shows how much the right search terms matter; I did search with different keywords — don't remember which — without success).